# Extracting a value from one python script that is executed in another python script

Tags: python, return-value

I have a script say test1.py that returns a value called uptime, I need to call the script test1.py in another python script and use the value uptime to store it into a sqlite db. How can I do this? I used this but it didn't work as expected:

```
    import time
    import random
    import sqlite3

    import test1.py
    print(uptime)
```

Obviously missing something here.

Comment: might want to read the python docs regarding modules https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: define a function in test1.py that return uptime and import that functions in the other script. That should work fine.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the repetition